# Trying to lookup a value from a pandas dataframe within a range of two rows in the index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have two dataframes - "*grower_moo*" and "*pricing*" in a Python notebook to analyze harvested crops and price payments to the growers.

*pricing* is the index dataframe, and *grower_moo* has various unique load tickets with information about each load.

I need to pull the price per ton from the *pricing* index to a new column in the load data if the *Fat* of that load is not greater than the next *Wet Fat*.

Below is a `.head()` sample of each dataframe and the code I tried. I received a `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects` error.

```
pricing
    Price_Per_Ton   Wet_Fat
0       306            10
1       339            11
2       382            12
3       430            13
4       481            14
5       532            15
6       580            16
7       625            17
8       665            18
9       700            19
10      728            20
11      750            21
12      766            22
13      778            23
14      788            24
15      797            25

grower_moo
    Load Ticket     Net Fruit Weight  Net MOO  Percent_MOO  Fat
0   L2019000011817     56660           833     1.448872    21.92
1   L2019000011816     53680           1409    2.557679    21.12
2   L2019000011815     53560           1001    1.834644    21.36
3   L2019000011161     62320           2737    4.207080    21.41
4   L2019000011160     57940           1129    1.911324    20.06
```

`grower_moo['price_per_ton'] = max(pricing[pricing['Wet_Fat'] < grower_moo['Fat']]['Price_Per_Ton'])`

Example output - `grower_moo['Fat']` of 13.60 is less than 14 Fat, therefore gets a price per ton of $430

```
grower_moo_with_price
    Load Ticket     Net Fruit Weight  Net MOO  Percent_MOO  Fat    price_per_ton
0   L2019000011817     56660           833     1.448872    21.92      750
1   L2019000011816     53680           1409    2.557679    21.12      750
2   L2019000011815     53560           1001    1.834644    21.36      750
3   L2019000011161     62320           2737    4.207080    21.41      750
4   L2019000011160     57940           1129    1.911324    20.06      728
```

Comment: To clarify, is this what you mean: for each value in `grower_moo['Fat']`, find the largest value of `pricing['Wet_Fat']` which is *less than* `grower_moo['Fat']`, and insert the corresponding `Price_Per_Ton` into a new column of `grower_moo`?

Comment: Precisely. Based on the `grower_moo['Fat']`, insert the correct price per ton as a new column in `grower_moo`.

I will provide a doctored sample output in my post.

Comment: I think I am getting to the right track with `.loc`... but not quite.

```pricing.loc[grower_moo['Fat'], 'Price_Per_Ton']``` 

This returns NaN for each `grower_moo['Fat']` value.

Comment: The example output description doesn't match the example output table, but I think I get the idea

Comment: Nice catch, I corrected the example output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a job for an "as of" merge, `pd.merge_asof` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)):

> This is similar to a left-join except that we match on nearest key
>   rather than equal keys. Both DataFrames must be sorted by the key.
>
> For each row in the left DataFrame:
>
> A "backward" search [the default]
>   selects the last row in the right DataFrame whose ‘on’ key is less
>   than or equal to the left’s key.

In the following code, I use your example inputs, but with column names using underscores `_` instead of spaces .

```
# Required by merge_asof: sort keys in left DataFrame
grower_moo = grower_moo.sort_values('Fat')

# Required by merge_asof: key column data types must match
pricing['Wet_Fat'] = pricing['Wet_Fat'].astype('float') 

# Perform the asof merge
res = pd.merge_asof(grower_moo, pricing, left_on='Fat', right_on='Wet_Fat')

# Print result
res
      Load_Ticket  Net_Fruit_Weight  Net_MOO  Percent_MOO    Fat  Price_Per_Ton  Wet_Fat
0  L2019000011160             57940     1129     1.911324  20.06            728     20.0
1  L2019000011816             53680     1409     2.557679  21.12            750     21.0
2  L2019000011815             53560     1001     1.834644  21.36            750     21.0
3  L2019000011161             62320     2737     4.207080  21.41            750     21.0
4  L2019000011817             56660      833     1.448872  21.92            750     21.0

# Optional: drop the key column from the right DataFrame
res.drop(columns='Wet_Fat')
      Load_Ticket  Net_Fruit_Weight  Net_MOO  Percent_MOO    Fat  Price_Per_Ton
0  L2019000011160             57940     1129     1.911324  20.06            728
1  L2019000011816             53680     1409     2.557679  21.12            750
2  L2019000011815             53560     1001     1.834644  21.36            750
3  L2019000011161             62320     2737     4.207080  21.41            750
4  L2019000011817             56660      833     1.448872  21.92            750
```

Comment: This is perfect. You are awesome. I upvoted and checked "Answered". Thanks for bearing with my explanation & examples. Had never heard of "merge_asof" - clever!

Comment: I don't control the database this dataset sits on, so I am left to work with the column headers they provide and haven't spent the time to clean them all up for this analysis. Thanks again

Comment: Glad to hear and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
concat_df = pd.concat([grower_moo, pricing], axis)
cocnat_df = concat_df[concat_df['Wet_Fat'] < concat_df['Fat']]
del cocnat_df['Wet_Fat']
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, but this only joins the dataframes through concatenation. There are only 16 rows in the *pricing* index dataframe, but there are over 800 rows of *grower_moo* data, so this will not work. I need a lookup from the *pricing* index into the new *grower_moo* column.

Comment: You can also concat only the relevant columns